# Firefox saves the file without extension

Tags: windows-7, firefox, file-extension

When I download a file, Firefox removes the file extension. I mean, if I download "something.pdf", it saves the file as "something". I didn't have this problem before yesterday.

Any help would be appreciated...

Edit: But I can open them by right click and open with. Only problem is the file name. I barely used my home pc in last two days and I'm really curious about what happened.
I tried to reset everything revelant to downloading and file extensions in "about:config". But no difference...

Comment: Did you check that the folder you're saving the file into is not configured to hide file extensions?

Comment: your files extensions removed or just not shown??

Comment: @JustinPearce: Good question, although that option is not folder-specific.

Comment: if you double click the file and it opens correctly, then "Hide Extensions" is enabled.

Comment: Of course they're removed. And when I rename them and add the file extension, they open correctly...

Comment: @s.alem Perhaps edit and add that info the question (the fact that you can't open them until you rename and add the extension).

Comment: Also, did you try a Windows System Restore back to a point before "yesterday", when it worked?  What _have_ you tried already?

Comment: But I can open them by right click and open with. Only problem is the file name. I barely used my home pc in last two days and I'm really curious about what happened...

Comment: I tried to reset everything revelant to downloading end file extensions in "about:config". But no difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save all your bookmarks, passwords, etc.

Then, try the following:

[image]
[image]

Comment: The most radical solution and worked. Thanks a lot. But I wish I could know why that happened...

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to post a comment, apologies.  It might not have to do with you or your browser.  The website might have just posted an update that now forgets to put the extension on the item.  This happens a lot more then people realize with bad testing or no testing.  Can you replicate the issue on another computer.  If you can replicate it on another computer, I would send a note to the owner of the site.

Comment: It's not about the website, because i've already tried differents websites. I can't replicate the problem, because I have no idea what's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Issue; Saving with the pre-defiined name works OK i.e save extension But changing the name during save process prompts message that no extension and you can force original extension name.

Resolve:

Open Folder Options.
Click View Tab
Untick 'Hide extensions for known file types' (which is the default setting for some reason) and now you see extension when changing name.

May not be the same isssue exactly but I laned here when trying to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

In your profile folder, there is a `handlers.json` file. Rename it to `handlers.json.old`, then restart Firefox. You can open your profile folder from within Firefox by following [these steps](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile).

If that doesn't work, you can see a list of other potential solutions here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/cant-download-or-save-files.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps anyone facing this problem
I fixed my problem by removing one of the browser extensions that related to a download manager "ninja download manager"

have a good day

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).